# Use PHP to change multiple number to another number

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

In text, i have a lot of time number, then i want to change hour to another timezone (+6), example :

00:15 => 06:15

01:00 => 07:00

... and so on.
I'm trying this :

```
$result = str_replace(
  array("00:","01:","02:","03:","04:","05:","06:","07:","08:","09:","10:","11:","12:","13:","14:","15:","16:","17:","18:","19:","20:","21:","22:","23:"),
    array("06:","07:","08:","09:","10:","11:","12:","13:","14:","15:","16:","17:","18:","19:","20:","21:","22:","23:","00:","01:","02:","03:","04:", "05:"),
    $text
);
 echo $result;
```

But 18: will replace with 04: because php replace 18: to 22: then continue replace 22: to 04:

How to solved this, thank you.

// **Edit** : To @user3414969 and @Medda86: $text is the data i'm get from another site, that mean i can not control the source, only way to do is replace

// **Edit 2** : Here is content : http://bongdatv.net/test.php

// **Edit 3**: Please solve this problem with replace way, not calculation number way.

Comment: you just need to add 6 hour in time right

Answer (score 1):

I think best is to use the timestamp format, add the time and get out the new time from that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: I just not control $text because i'm get data from another site.

Comment: just loop the array and run the time function on each value :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
$time = array("00:","01:","02:","03:","04:","05:","06:","07:","08:","09:","10:","11:","12:","13:","14:","15:","16:","17:","18:","19:","20:","21:","22:","23:");

$required_time = array();
    
foreach($time as $t){
    $hour = $t."00"; // 00 appending 0 minites
    $hours_plus = 6; // adding 6 hours
    $required_time[] = date('H:', strtotime($hour)+($hours_plus*60*60));
}
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($required_time);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Result:(
    [0] => 06:
    [1] => 07:
    [2] => 08:
    [3] => 09:
    [4] => 10:
    [5] => 11:
    [6] => 12:
    [7] => 13:
    [8] => 14:
    [9] => 15:
    [10] => 16:
    [11] => 17:
    [12] => 18:
    [13] => 19:
    [14] => 20:
    [15] => 21:
    [16] => 22:
    [17] => 23:
    [18] => 00:
    [19] => 01:
    [20] => 02:
    [21] => 03:
    [22] => 04:
    [23] => 05:
)

Comment: how to apply to my code, just try : `$result = str_replace($time, $required_time, $text);  echo $result;` but not work. Sorry i'm bad with php.

Comment: str_replace is for string, not for array. That's why I used foreach loop to generate your required result

Answer (score 0):

Optimal way is as suggested by Medda86 
However, you can try upon this way

```
$array = ("00:","01:",....);
//Then you can loop over array and add the time 
for($i=0 ; $i < sizeof($array);$i++){
       $array[$i] = intval($array[$i]+6)%24;
       if($array[$i] < 10)
         $array[$i] = str_pad($array[$i],2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':';
       else
         $array[$i] .= ':';
}
```

Comment: I need **00:**, not 0. Because in $text have another number that i do not to change.

Comment: Please look at URL : http://bongdatv.net/test.php

I need change time match start, not score number.

Comment: for the above code foll $array is :array(24) { [0]=> string(3) "06:" [1]=> string(3) "07:" [2]=> string(3) "08:" [3]=> string(3) "09:" [4]=> string(3) "10:" [5]=> string(3) "11:" [6]=> string(3) "12:" [7]=> string(3) "13:" [8]=> string(3) "14:" [9]=> string(3) "15:" [10]=> string(3) "16:" [11]=> string(3) "17:" [12]=> string(3) "18:" [13]=> string(3) "19:" [14]=> string(3) "20:" [15]=> string(3) "21:" [16]=> string(3) "22:" [17]=> string(3) "23:" [18]=> string(3) "00:" [19]=> string(3) "01:" [20]=> string(3) "02:" [21]=> string(3) "03:" [22]=> string(3) "04:" [23]=> string(3) "05:" }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$yourArr = array('00:15','01:00','00:30');
foreach ($yourArr as $key => $value) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($value) + 60*60*6; // add hours as per your need.
    $time = date('H:i', $timestamp);
    $newArr[] = $time;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
```

**Result is:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06:15
    [1] => 07:00
    [2] => 06:30
)
```